# Is it possible to take horizontal photo when tablet is in Portrait mode using UWP and MediaCapture?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I am working on windows 10 tablet app and one of requirements is that app should be locked in portrait mode and user should be able to take horizontal photo while holding tablet in portrait (vertical) position. 
My question is if is it even possible? Isn't it camera hardware restriction and just how camera works? For sure it would be one of its kind:) It will be in UWP and MediaCapture will be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to take horizontal photo when tablet is in Portrait mode using UWP and MediaCapture?

I know your requirement, Unfortunately, UWP does not provide such property for `MediaCapture`.

The camera will get more view-able area when your device in Landscape model. Base on your screen display area, vertical [`VideoPreview`](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit/cs/MainPage.xaml.cs#L331) will be cut out areas beyond the sides of the screen.    and capture photo comes from `VideoPreview`, but VideoPreview does not provide api for zooming preview so that it can fill the entire vertical screen.